# Is there a way for @SpyBean to create spies for all types based on the interface type in a Spring Boot test?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mockito, spring-test

I have a Spring Boot application where I would like to ensure that a list of decorators are verified to be executed. These decorators all extend from the same Abstract class, which in turn extend from the same interface, and they are autowired into a service class as a list of decorators. I would have thought that providing the `@SpyBean(MyDecorator.class)` at the class level of the test would have done the trick, but I got the error specifying that the decorator is not a spy. It looks like the `MockitoPostProcessor` class expects that we provide the individual concrete classes in the annotation as so `@SpyBean(classes = {decorator1.class,decorator2.class})`. I tried the latter, and it worked.

However, the issue that I have with this is that we have to add to this list every time we create a new decorator, which is not ideal. This is why I thought it makes sense to have the interface type be checked as well. Please let me know if there is a better way of doing this, or if I missed something. A thought that crossed my mind was to define my own post processor to wrap any bean from a defined type in a mockito spy, but I would like to check here first. Here is a skeleton definition of the classes to help you understand my dilemma.

MyDecorator.java

```
public interface MyDecorator{
    public void decorate(SomeObject obj);
}
```

AbstractDecorator.java

```
public class AbstractDecorator implements MyDecorator{
    //common decorator logic
}
```

Decorator1.java

```
@Component
public class Decorator1 extends AbstractDecorator{
    public void decorate(SomeObject obj){
        //decoration logic
    }
}
```

Decorator2.java

```
@Component
public class Decorator2 extends AbstractDecorator{
    public void decorate(SomeObject obj){
        //decoration logic
    }
}
```

DecorationService.java

```
@Service
public class DecorationService implements Service{

    @Autowired
    private List<MyDecorator> decoratorList;


    public void processDecorators(){
        //go through list of decorators and process some object
    }
}
```

DecoratorServiceTest.java

```
@Runwith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
//@SpyBean(MyDecorator.class) //<-- This doesn't wrap the classes in a spy and errors out
@SpyBean(classes = {Decorator1.class, Decorator2.class}) //<-- This works
public class DecoratorServiceTest{
    @Autowired
    private List<MyDecorator> decoratorList;

    @Test
    public void testProcessDecorator(){
        //verify that each decorator was processed
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted a spring boot github issue [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/28903). Hopefully we would either see an improvement on it or we get an explanation as to why it is designed in this way.

I have a workaround in place that I'm using which is I've created a class that  implements Spring's `BeanPostProcessor` interface, and I override the `postProcessAfterInitialization` method, and I check if the class is what I'm expecting, then I would wrap it in a mockito spy. Also, you would need to define the spring bean.

Here is a snippet of the class that I created.

```
public class SpyBeanPostProcessor<T> implements BeanPostProcessor{

    /**
     * The class type to spy on.
     */
    private Class<T> typeToSpy;

    /**
     * Construct a SpyBeanPostProcessor with a class type to wrap
     * as a {@link org.mockito.Spy}
     * @param typeToSpy The class type to spy on.
     */
    public SpyBeanPostProcessor(Class<T> typeToSpy) {
        this.typeToSpy = typeToSpy;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        if (typeToSpy.isAssignableFrom(bean.getClass())){
            return Mockito.spy(bean);
        }else{
            return bean;
        }
    }
}
```

I also needed to create a new spring bean that loads the `BeanPostProcessor` as shown below.

```
    @Bean
    public static SpyBeanPostProcessor decoratorSpyBeanPostProcessor(){
        return new SpyBeanPostProcessor(MyDecorator.class);
    }
```